# Iterating over a text file to read the lines into a class module in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

What I actually need to do: Read a text file into VBA and have every line of the file be a separate instance of a class module

I have data in a text file like

```
2018-08-10 12:00:00 | B | 34328 | SPY | ARCA || 100 | 200.4
2018-08-10 13:43:00 | B | 343 | SPY | ARCA || 100 | 200.8
2018-08-10 13:50:00 | S | 2809 | SPY || 100 | 201.2
2018-08-10 13:55:00 | B | 34878 | SPY || 100 | 200.9
```

I'm doing a VBA exercise. I need to read that file into a class module, so that each instance of the module is one line of the file. Eventually, I will have to do analysis with the numbers contained.

My guidelines are:
-The file should only have to be read once
-The code must be pure vba - I should not have to modify an existing spreadsheet

So far I have tried:

-- creating the class module

```
' Class Module: Trade
Public Fill As String
```

--- in a different module

```
Public myFile As String
Sub defineVar()
myFile = Range("$A$2")
End Sub
Sub readFills()

Call defineVar

Dim dict
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Dim fill_ID As Long
fill_ID = 0

Open myFile For Input As #1

Do Until EOF(1)
Line Input #1, fileLine
dict.Add Key:=fill_ID, Item:=fileLine
 Dim name As New trade
 name.Fill = dict(fill_ID)
 fill_ID = fill_ID + 1
 Debug.Print name.Fill
Loop
Close #1

End Sub
```

This works in that it reads every line of the file, but I only end up with one instance (the final line of the file), though I have a full dictionary. Is it possible to dynamically create "instances" of a class module? Am I going about it the wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make several changes to your code.  First, declare your class variable outside the loop.  Second, create a new instance inside the loop.  Third, add that instance to a collection.  For example,

```
Dim name As Trade
Dim names As Collection

Set names = New Collection
Open myFile For Input As #1

Do Until EOF(1)
   Line Input #1, fileLine
   dict.Add Key:=fill_ID, item:=fileLine
   Set name = New Trade
   name.Fill = dict(fill_ID)
   names.Add name
   fill_ID = fill_ID + 1
   Debug.Print name.Fill
Loop

Close #1
```

Comment: Thank you - this worked, but I'm still confused about a couple of things.
a) Would I not want every instance of trade to have a unique name?
b) I tried to write "Debug.Print lines" and I got the error "wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment". Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

```
Do Until EOF(1)
Line Input #1, fileLine
dict.Add Key:=fill_ID, Item:=fileLine
 Dim name As New trade
 name.Fill = dict(fill_ID)
 fill_ID = fill_ID + 1
 Debug.Print name.Fill
Loop
Close #1
```

In the code above it looks as if your 'trade' object is overwritten on each iteration of the loop (which is why you only see the last line of your file).

If you want all lines of your file as a collection of objects of the 'trade' type you should add them to a container.  I often use collections for this, eg:

```
dim trades as New Collection
```

then in the loop you simply write

```
trades.add name 'this creates a collection of trade objects from each line from the file
```

you could do something similar if you added the trade object name to the dictionary which is also a collection